# Javascript Regular Expression to restrict user from Entering same consecutive digits in a text field

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I want to restrict the user from entering same consecutive digits in a text field e.g User can't enter string like John22 or 22John or jo22hn....He can enter string like Joh2n2 , 2Joh2n and so on...All this has to be done in Javascript (Using regular expressions would be a better option)...Please help

Comment: @BonyT - What if people paste text into the control, drag text to it, undo, etc. You can almost never rely on key events.

Answer (score 3):

Test a string for consecutive digits:

```
/(\d)\1/.test(string)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using a negative lookahead.

```
^(?!.*(\d)\1).*$
```

See it [here at Regexr](http://regexr.com?2u6m5)

The `^` and the `$` anchor the match at the start and the end of the string.

`.*` Will match everything (except newline characters)

The important part here is the Negative lookahead `(?!.*(\d)\1)` it will check the whole string for a digit `\d` put it in a capture group because of the brackets `(\d)` and reuse the value using the backreference `\1` and the whole thing fails it there is a digit followed by the same digit.

Comment: Aside from that, I'm still learning regex, so wondered if and how yours is better than my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex should help:

```
/[0-9]{2,}/
```

Or

```
/[\d]{2,}/
```

Although, you can match for all instances using the /g flag:

```
/[0-9]{2,}/g
```

See it at [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uFYyj/1/)